# Automatically save PDF displayed in WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a C# WinForms app that runs the WebBrowser control to automatically login, navigate through some pages, and ultimately arrive to page that displays a PDF.  I would like to automatically save this PDF whenever I arrive to this page but I have been unable to do this automatically.

Is there a way to automatically click "save" in the webBrowser1.ShowSaveAsDialog() window?  Or is there another way to save the PDF that I have successfully displayed in the webbrowser?

Additionally, I have tried to download the PDF using WebClient but this returns a HTML page with failed user/password info. Also, webBrowser1.Document is null so I'm unable to access the document as I would other pages in this routine.

Comment: Did you solve this? I've exactly the same problem...

Comment: Just realized you responded to this.  No, I was never able to solve it the way I asked in this post.  I ended up using the web request class and parsing the response.